# Postgresql say “schema does not exist”

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql

How can I make this query works?

I've the function `top_movies_ceiling(3)`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION top_movies_ceiling(n_top integer)  -- n_top dos mais vendidos
RETURNS SETOF inventory AS $$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY
SELECT *
FROM inventory
ORDER BY sales DESC
LIMIT n_top;
END;
$$LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

that returns:

```
prod_id|quan_in_stock|sales
```

Now, when I run the query:

```
SELECT products.price 
FROM products
WHERE products.prod_id = prod_id.top_movies_ceiling(3);
```

I get the error: `schema "prod_id" does not exist`

I hope that you can help me!
Thanks!

Comment: why you use `prod_id.top_movies_ceilin`?..

Comment: Because I've opened a Cursor and i've been fetch it into a numeric variable from the same type that "prod_id", for the purpose to save it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a wild guess - is it what you try to do?

```
SELECT products.price 
FROM products
JOIN (select * from top_movies_ceiling(3)) top_m on top_m.prod_id = products.prod_id
;
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is in:

> prod_id.top_movies_ceiling(3)

that mean: function top_movies_ceiling(int) from schema prod_id.

Please enter the CREATE FUNCTION of top_movies_ceiling() for better understand what you want.